# Define a nose test method inside a nose test class

Tags: python, python-3.x, nose

Define a nose test method `test_circlearea_with_min_radius`, which creates a circle `c2` with radius 0 and check if it's computed area matches the value 0

I have written below mentioned code but still, I am not getting the desired output:

```
import math
from circle import Circle
from nose.tools import assert_raises
from nose.tools import assert_equal


class Circle:

    def __init__(self,radius):

        if not isinstance(radius,(int,float)):
            raise TypeError("radius must be a number")

        if not 1000>=radius>=0:
            raise ValueError("radius must be between 0 and 1000 inclusive")

        self.radius = radius


    def area(self):
        return round(math.pi*self.radius**2,2)

    def circumference(self):
        return round(2*math.pi*self.radius,2)


class TestCircleArea:

    def test_circlearea_with_random_numeric_radius(self):
        c1=Circle(2.5)
        assert_equal(c1.area(),19.63)

    def test_circlearea_with_min_radius(self):
        c2=Circle(0)
        assert_equal(c2.area(),0)
```

Comment: I was able to get your test to run fine in nosetests. How are you trying to run your tests? If your above code is in a file called e.g., test.py, you should be able to run your tests with `nosetests test.py`.

Comment: i am trying to complete one hands on NOSE test using katacoda.  i am not able to get it through.  I will update my code. kindly suggest

Answer (score 0):

To get your test to run, you will have to execute the file with `nose`; you cannot execute it like a normal python script. For example, if the code from your post were in a file called `test.py`, you could run the following command:

```
nosetests test.py
```

If you run the command `python test.py` you will get no output. Depending on how you named your files, etc., you should just be able to run `nosetests` with no argument, and nose's test discovery should be smart enough to find your test class and run the test. Also, make sure you import/define your `Circle` class before running tests on it or you will get an error from that.

If you were trying to write the `Circle` class yourself, and wanted to build it the fun way with TDD, you could start with something like this:

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(*args):
        pass

    def area(self):
        pass

from nose.tools import assert_equals
class TestCircleArea:

    def test_circlearea_with_random_numeric_radius(self):
        c1=Circle(0)
        assert_equals(c1.area(),0)
```

This would give you a failing test, and you could start to build the functionality of the `area()` method from there, [going from red (failing test) to green (passing test)](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/tdd-red-green-refactor).